# Iframe option in google apps-script

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script

Is it possible to display a website (eg. www.google.com ) using iframe  in the sidebar of google docs while developing using app-script  iframe .'X-Frame-Options' to 'same-origin' , error is occurring . I tried setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

Still the same error occurs.

## Screenshot Link

[Click this link for screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk9vM.png)

===========

## Code.gs

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
function onOpen(e){
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("IframeOptions").addItem("iFrame",'sviFrame').addToUi();
}
function sviFrame(){
 var iframe =  HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Iframe').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

  /*var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Iframe')
    .evaluate()
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);*/

 DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(iframe);
}
```

=============

## Iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com" height="1500" width="100%"></iframe>
  </body>
  <script>
  alert(google.script.sandbox.mode);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post some of your code.

Comment: @Brian I have edited the post .